# How show all queries to database in yii framework

Tags: yii

In CodeIgniter I would do:

```
print_r ($this->db->queries);
```

In Yii I tried:

```
 print_r (Yii::app()->db)
```

But this doesn't show any queries.

UPDATE:
I understand my problem: when I want to show db queries on a `POST` action, I don't show it. When using `GET`, it's ok.

Comment: http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/11403-knowing-last-query/

Comment: did you use CWebLogRoute also?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As @bool.dev said, you can use `CWebLogRoute` or in my case i use `CFileLogRoute` to store these queries in file.

```
array (
    'class'      => 'CFileLogRoute',
    'categories' => 'system.db.*',
    'logFile'    => 'sql.log',
),
```

Comment: For me CWebLogRoute better.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

To complement @snippLeaf-com's answer, you can trace this file filtering by the keywords you want like this:

```
// filter by "INSERT" or "UPDATE"
$ tail -f /path_to/protected/runtime/sql.log |grep 'INSERT\|UPDATE'

// filter (case insensitive) by "SELECT" in table "x2_users"
$ tail -f /path_to/protected/runtime/sql.log |grep -i SELECT.*x2_users
```

OBS: to get fresh data you could need refresh database cache:

```
rm -f protected/runtime/cache/*.bin
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really want every query log in **yii** use [**yii db profiler**](https://github.com/samdark/yii-db-profiler) extension.

**Step1**. Download extension from  --> [link](https://github.com/samdark/yii-db-profiler)

**Step2**. Unpack to `protected/extensions/`

**Step3**. Rename folder name `yii-db-profiler-master` to `db_profiler`

**Step4**. Update the following to your `protected/config/main.php`:

```
<?php
return array(
    // …
    'components' => array(
        // …
        'db' => array(
            // …
            'enableProfiling'=>true,
            'enableParamLogging' => true,
        ),
        'log'=>array(
            'class'=>'CLogRouter',
            'routes'=>array(
                    // …
                    array(
                        'class'=>'ext.db_profiler.DbProfileLogRoute',
                        'countLimit' => 1, // How many times the same query should be executed to be considered inefficient
                        'slowQueryMin' => 0.01, // Minimum time for the query to be slow
                    ),
            ),
        ),
    ),
);
```